# how to build spring-session module source code with eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-session

I want to use spring-session module. but I find the origin source code is not totally meet my need. so I need to modify some code and build it again.but I don't know how to do it? do you have any suggestion to me? thanks.

other 1:

My development environment is JDK 8, Eclipse neon(with grade), Maven3.2.

source code git :https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session

other 2:

I have checkouted the source code and  compiled successful. now the problem is how to deploy jar to maven repository with gradle.

Comment: i have compiled this source code successful by use eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have had a extensive look at `spring-session`, but if it has at least the average quality of any other Spring project I suggest you just extending and overriding the components you need to rather than recompiling it. I have done it several times with `spring-security` due to custom requirements

This way, you would be able to update your dependences over spring-session as new versions are released.

Using maven, create a new maven project, just set spring-session as your project's maven dependency and extend, implement and override all you need. Next time spring-session is updated to a new release, you will just have to update your dependency to the last GA release and (after checking all is still OK) you won't be bind to a version which may get outdated someday.

Comment: yes, I have used this way now. but I want to learn more about spring, and I want to learn how to use gradle to deploy Jar to my maven repository. other: i do it like this. write the Java Class with the some package and class name, but this class is package in my project.org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration

Comment: You will be able to deploy your library to your maven repository, even if you do the way I suggest you. I think it is the best way rather than making a kind of fork or branch on it, but it's your decission then

Comment: because my project have a  class 'org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration' and the spring-session.jar have a some class. although my project class override the spring-session.jar class. but i think this way is not graceful. maybe this way make somebody confused.

Comment: I bet as per modularity and pluggability in Spring you could give your implementation a different package and just then configure the component which calls this to use yours instead of `spring-sessions`' one.

Comment: i want to use different package. but I can't. because the origin source code will auto initialize some code which i don't want to happen. so it must be the some package name and class name.

Answer (score 0):

To build Spring Session project from the source and install it in your local Maven repo use the following Gradle command:

```
$ ./gradlew install
```

The publishing will be done using `version` property declared in `gradle.properties` in the root of the project (at the moment, the master branch is on `1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`).

However, if you have some problem with Spring Session I'd consider reporting the issue on project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues).